# Подскажите плагин

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Здравствуйте, может кто-то встречал подобный плагин который описывается [здесь](http://bit.ly/1EkphYK), плагин интересный но дорогой, может знает кто такой же импортный? Может кто знает как реализовать подобное?

Comment: целый старт-ап на нем можно замутить)) бесплатно TeamViewer, и то, только для не коммерческого использования

Comment: TeamViewer это надо скачивать и устанавливать, никто этим заниматься не будет, а этот плагин сам встроен в сайт, наверняка он есть за рубежом, за приемлемую цену.

Comment: Теоретически можно сделать фрейм, в котором будут какие-то элементы, и для них получать координаты с другого сервера. Либо же получать какие-то блоки с координатами. Но это не делается за часа два, тут достаточно много и долго писать.

Answer (score 1):

Такую штуку можно сделать самостоятельно через сокеты. Но так как это трудозатратно, вряд ли вы найдете бесплатные аналоги, да и идея свежая.

Comment: Я не ищу бесплатный аналог, я ищу платный - но с адекватной ценой. Для меня это новое, я даже не знаю, как правильно загуглить. : )

Comment: Начинайте гуглить с websocket. Дальше websocket на nodejs. И вам откроются крутые штуки в режиме реалтайм.

Comment: @dogmar Я тут пару дней назад, отвечая на вопрос, [указал стек библиотек](http://hashcode.ru/questions/392060#392092), которые способны реализовать всё это. Почитайте.